# Test of programming skills during postdoctoral interview

Tags: postdocs, interview, code

I am going to have an interview for the postdoctoral position in the US which will include the test of programming skills in one programming language. Does anyone know what kind of exercise/difficulty level should I expect?

Comment: Does this postdoctoral position directly involve any programming work? If so, I'd expect the supervisor will want to check that you have the programming skills to do that work. So the test should be based on the sort of work you're expected to do as a postdoc.

Comment: If the position involves dealing with AI/ML, it is likely to assess whether you are actually capable of doing experiments with such technologies. A great deal of people (according to my experience) put "knowledge of AI/ML" in their resumes but very few are actually able to do something with it. Perhaps the test is for filtering out unsuitable candidates.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is not specific to the US, and I do not think any such answer can be given because the difficulty will depend on the interviewer.

Most of the time they simply want to know if you have the skills to do the job. Of course, some interviewers are more demanding than others when deciding how much skill is needed. However, a postdoc is often hired to "get the job done", and there usually is less time for learning new skills than during a PhD thesis. The fact that there is a technical programming interview does seem to indicate that they expect a candidate to have some programming experience .

A *good* technical interview is not unlike questions about a PhD thesis: the interviewer looks for your limits. This means that, provided they have the social and technical skill to design such an interview, it will contain both very basic and extremely advanced questions. Of course it is impossible to say whether this applies to your interview: it all depends on your interviewer.

Also, if you do get highly advanced questions, this does not necessarily mean that you have to be capable of answering them all: programming skills are (hopefully) only part of the assessment, and even if you cannot answer everything you may still be the best candidate.